# How to measure similarity between 2 timestamp series of events?

Tags: python, time-series, minhash

Suppose I have two timestamp series of events:

```
T1 = ['2017-03-22 15:16:45', '2017-03-22 15:16:50', '2017-03-22 15:17:55', ...]
T2 = ['2017-03-22 15:16:47', '2017-03-22 15:16:52', '2017-03-22 15:17:57', ...]
```

Each timestamp means the time it happend.

[They may look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJs1O.png)

We can tell that T2 is just a time-shift of T1, so they belong to the same pattern. The similarity should be 100%.

[They may also look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZckZO.png)

Here the similarity should be 50%.

I've read a paper saying we can apply LSH(Locality-Sensitive Hashing) to detect the similarity. But I don't know how to do it in detail. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried to compare the mean time between each event for each sample? It is a common approach because transform the problem in the domain of time into a problem in domain of frequencies. In that case this procedure is robust against offset displacement (different phase signals).

Comment: All means as far as I know to transform a discrete time-series to frequency domain is to use FFT. In fact, we can transform the problem in this way: Given two 0-1 series standing for two different events,for example[0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1] and [0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0] each bit means the event happened during specific time-bin. So which metric should I use to determine if they are similar? Are you familiar with LSH?